# Opencart add discount to shipping for certain product

Tags: php, opencart

I am trying to create a new 'Order Totals' extension for Opencart. The extension would add a discount to the shipping if a specific product is in the cart.

I have set up the new 'Order Totals' extension but I don't know how to check if the specific product in question is in the cart. So far I have:

```
if ($product['product_id'] == 108) { ... }
```

But this doesn't work. I presume I need to add more php in order to get all of the product id's in the cart but I simply don't have the knowledge.

Thank you

***EDIT***

Thank you to shadyyx and Jay Gilford, my code is now:

```
class ModelTotalKipper extends Model {
    public function getTotal(&$total_data, &$total, &$taxes) {
        $products = $this->cart->getProducts();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            if($product['product_id'] == 108) {
                if (($this->cart->getSubTotal() < $this->config->get('kipper_total')) && ($this->cart->getSubTotal() > 0)) {
                    $this->language->load('total/kipper');

                    $total_data[] = array( 
                        'code'       => 'kipper',
                        'title'      => $this->language->get('text_kipper'),
                        'text'       => $this->currency->format($this->config->get('kipper_fee')),
                        'value'      => $this->config->get('kipper_fee'),
                        'sort_order' => $this->config->get('kipper_sort_order')
                    );

                    if ($this->config->get('kipper_tax_class_id')) {
                        $tax_rates = $this->tax->getRates($this->config->get('kipper_fee'), $this->config->get('kipper_tax_class_id'));

                        foreach ($tax_rates as $tax_rate) {
                            if (!isset($taxes[$tax_rate['tax_rate_id']])) {
                                $taxes[$tax_rate['tax_rate_id']] = $tax_rate['amount'];
                            } else {
                                $taxes[$tax_rate['tax_rate_id']] += $tax_rate['amount'];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $total += $this->config->get('kipper_fee');
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: As @Jay said, switch the lines accordingly... I thought You know PHP... Check my updated answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess all You need then is this:

```
class ModelTotalKipper extends Model {
    public function getTotal(&$total_data, &$total, &$taxes) {
        $products = $this->cart->getProducts();

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            if($product['product_id'] == 108) {
                // do whatever You need here...
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If there will be more then one product to be discounted, then change the `if` slightly:

```
    if(in_array($product['product_id'], array(108, 109, 110))) {
        // do whatever You need here...
    } // no break; here in this case...
```

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
$products = $this->cart->getProducts();
```

Needs to be after this line

```
public function getTotal(&$total_data, &$total, &$taxes) {
```